# Element in layout isn't showing up (covered up by another element)

Tags: android, layout, text, scroll, textview

Here's the layout for a custom Alert Dialog I've been working on. It's just a TextView with a CheckBox underneath:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/help_dialog_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</ScrollView>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/display_help_dialogs_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/display_help_dialogs" />
```

When the TextView's textSize is sufficiently large (i.e. when the ScrollView is actually "put to use"), the CheckBox is nowhere to be seen.

Thanks for the help,
Mitchell

Comment: just wrap the whole above code in another scrollview.

Comment: @Urban: Hmm... I'm curious how a scrollview would handle having another scrollview contained inside it.

Comment: oh right..hmm...come to think of it, now even im curious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your `ScrollView` is pushing the `Checkbox` outside the bounds of the layout.  Try something like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/help_dialog_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/display_help_dialogs_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/display_help_dialogs" />
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

You may need to specify dimensions of the scrollview in this case, but what should happen is the `LinearLayout` becomes bigger than the area designated in the `ScrollView`.  The `ScrollView` will then allow the user to scroll down the layout to see the rest.

Comment: Perfect. I initially tried to put both the TextView and CheckBox into a ScrollView, but a ScrollView can only have one child... so I gave up and posted this question. And of course, the solution is so simple!